# How can I launch and close jQuery Twitter Bootstrap Modal with a YouTube video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

I need a simple demo of how to launch and close a YouTube video in a [Twitter Bootstrap Modal](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) from JavaScript (rather than an anchor tag click).

So far I can launch it just fine, but on close it keeps playing in the background.

Here's my html:

```
<div id="myModalThumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x150&text=Video%20Thumbnail">
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe width="520" height="390" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Javascript:

```
$('#myModalThumbnail').click(function () {
    var src = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/KVu3gS7iJu4&amp;rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1';
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $('#myModal iframe').attr('src', src);
});
```

​
And a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VtKS8/5/): http://jsfiddle.net/VtKS8/5/

What next?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, looks like all I needed to do was remove the `src` attribute on the button click.

```
$('#myModal button').click(function () {
    $('#myModal iframe').removeAttr('src');
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VtKS8/6/

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to get the same thing and control the video but with the iFrame API and ran into browser incompatibilities. This feels like a side effect but does the trick very well so far.

Comment: but when you press escape it still plays

Comment: For `esc`, add something like this: `$(document).keydown(function(e){if (e.keyCode === 27) {$('#myModal iframe').removeAttr('src');}});`  See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VtKS8/33/  Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is the updated version for bootstrap 3 using the built in bootstrap hooks

```
<script>
     $( document ).ready(function() {
       $('#audiomodal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $( "audio" ).attr('src', '');
       });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Any chance of a fiddle or a url of a page with this working? Best wishes, Lee.